Page number after clearpage, definitely known?
This is a simple question, but all previous questions (that I could find) involved complicated situations.
Using pdflatex and lualatex: Immediately after the \clearpage command, does the new page know its page number immediately? That is, in any document class, without using any special packages, if I write
\clearpage
\typeout{PAGE=\thepage}
% Possibly other material to follow on the page; possibly not.

Will that show the correct page number? I have experimented, and my various trials all show it to be correct. Or is there a situation that I missed?
EDIT: Most readers should see the answer and comments, appearing below. My specific application is very narrow, and I did not wish to ask the question in a way that nobody else could use. But here is what I am doing:
I have an environment "onepageonly". Its content must be confined to one page. It does not contain any floats, or things that might float. It contains only ordinary text, and possibly a png raster image.
\newenvironment{onepageonly}{
\clearpage
\edef\startpagenumber{\arabic{c@page}}
% Nothing here re-sets the page count.
}{
\clearpage
\edef\lastpagenumber{\arabic{c@page}}
% Then I compare the two page numbers using more code.
% If the lastpagenumber = startpagenumber +1, good. Else error.
}

That always seems to work. The concept is: If the contents required
a second page, no matter how short, then the final \clearpage
would move to yet another page, and the count would be too much.
Note that I do not actually need to know the page numbers. I only need to know the increment.

I think it would be a little bit more robust (but not robust) if you did the check prior to \clearpage. but better might be to box the lot and check whether it exceeds the page dimensions. then unpack the box if it fits and either error or unpack and warn if not. that way you don't have to worry about additions to either the end of onepageonly or \clearpage or the shipout routine, any of which might interfere with the numbering. of course, if this code is for purely personal use, that's less of a concern.

@cfr The box/unbox method might be a better approach. I don't really care what the page numbers are. I only care whether the content fits on one page (and was counting pages, for that purpose). Will have a look at box/unbox, but not immediately. If you are curious: The page content is a legal notice, which must be on exactly one page. But it is not necessarily a specific page number.

@rallg In your place I'd definitely use a couple of ltproperties labels with the abspage property, which is available out-of-the-box (no packages, that's in the kernel), than you can compare with \property_ref:nn directly which is expandable. I'd probably only \clearpage at the start, the one at the end looks to me as just "the wrong way to try to get the page number".

@gusbrs but those are only reliable inside the shipout routine. o/w they can be out by one. and they depend on the .aux.

@cfr Yes, of course, it is a cross-reference. And it is because it is that the value will be correct, since the value is indeed expanded at shipout rather than immediately. And what's the problem with the .aux file? (It feels like I'm missing something, since you two seem to be worried about this...).

@gusbrs I am not worried about it. but I strongly suspect this is for a class which is intentionally (and, in some cases, probably unintentionally) incompatible which many standard latex features. I haven't really looked into it, but I think the class blocks much usage of the aux file. i didn't make this connection when I wrote my answer - only after seeing the response to your comments.

@cfr I had a cool idea and added an answer, take a look.  ;-)  I think you're gonna like it too.

No.
Consider:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\typeout{Page \thepage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}

\end{document}


The console output reports Page ii. Is that correct? Technically, yes, but it is not the value of \thepage for the content which immediately follows. Whether that's an issue for your use case or not depends on the use case, which you've not explained.
Or consider,
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Something
\clearpage
\typeout{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{43}%
more
\end{document}

where the console reports 2 but the page number turns out to be 43. That might seem nefarious, but something like
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Something
\clearpage
\typeout{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
more
\end{document}

may be perfectly sensible. Here, the console reports 2, but \thepage turns out to be I and the value of the counter page is 1.
Note that you do not need to alter the numbering scheme or interfere with the numbering sequence, either directly or indirectly.
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\typeout{Page \thepage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\clearpage
\typeout{Page \thepage}
\chapter{two}
\clearpage

\end{document}

will output Page 2 on the console, though the content which follows is on page 3. As in the first case, 2 is technically correct, so that might be sufficient for your purposes. But it is not sufficient if you want to know which page the content immediately following is on.
If you need to know the page number for some reason, use the absolute value instead, which is not supposed to be written, but only read.

All of the example change the output of \thepage (directly or indirectly), so definitely it will be different. But if you don't change that, would the answer be yes?

@Werner technically, but is that useful? I mean, if you expect the content which immediately follows to be on the given page then, no, because obviously something may insert another \shipout. but if you really only want to know the output of \thepage in the moment, maybe?

My own use case would not have "constructed" content (such as table of contents) or floats, or page count reset. So then, the answer to my question is "no" as originally asked, but "yes" for my limited usage situation. For most TeX users, who do have other things happening, your explanation is very useful.

@rallg but depending on your use case, it would still probably be better to use the absolute page number i.e. the count of shipouts rather than the result of \thepage or the value of page.

Yes, I will use the absolute page number, which is actually better for my purpose. Is there a macro that provides the absolute page number? I can construct it, if necessary, but would rather use a built-in function.

Ah, I see that the ltshipout documentation describes how to get the absolute page number (secition 1.6).

@rallg yes, see ltshipout 1.6 Information counters. but note that even this value may 'out by one' in the body of the document.

@cfr Why not include the traditional \label{foo}/\pageref{foo} as a way to get the right value? ("as typeset" as opposed to the shipout absolute counters).

@gusbrs I was under the impression that the label-pageref method is only reliable when performing a second compile. My original question needs the info "right now".

@rallg Yes, the cross-reference will only be available after writing the label to the .aux file. But after that, it will be available at the time it is needed. But why ever would you need to restrict things to "work on the first run after clearing the .aux"?

@rallg the page count isn't reliable without multiple compilations. in some cases, it produces an extra page at the end telling you so. note what the docs say: neither page nor the absolute page are reliable outside ship out. if you need something you can rely on, neither of these fit that bill unless you can do whatever you need to do within that process. e.g. positioning a watermark for odd/even pages can be done that way.

@rallg I took a closer look at the application you have in mind (it was not there when I first read the question and I had missed 'til now) and it seems you are trying to do something like what varioref does to catch possible loop situations. And, spoiler alert, varioref uses two cross-references to do the check.

I think @cfr's answer does handle the question that was actually asked in the OP, but there's still some discussion in the comments regarding the use case at hand.
I suggested that a pair of ltproperties labels at the beginning/end of the environment, using the abspage property, and then compare the values at the end and issue an error in case they differ. ltproperties' \property_ref:nn is already expandable, so it can be conveniently used to make the comparison.
That's how I'd go. But for some reason I don't understand there is some concern in the comments with the use of a cross-reference, or maybe that it needs more than one run, or that uses the .aux. I don't get it, and I might be missing something.
But there is yet a way that meets all these requirements. I had no intention of answering, but I've been playing with ltmarks this week, and it proved extremely useful in a concrete use case of mine, sparing me of a lot of work. So I don't mind including an answer here to advertise a bit this very cool kernel module.
Here how it could go:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mysamepage}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{onepageonly}{}
  {%
    \clearpage%
    \InsertMark{mysamepage}{begin}%
  }
  {\InsertMark{mysamepage}{end}}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}
  {%
    \IfMarksEqualT{mysamepage}{first}{last}
      {\PackageError{rallg}{Doesn't fit in one page on \thepage}{}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{onepageonly}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{onepageonly}

\begin{onepageonly}
  \lipsum[1-6]
\end{onepageonly}

\begin{onepageonly}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{onepageonly}

\begin{onepageonly}
  \lipsum[1-6]
\end{onepageonly}

\end{document}

The idea is simple: we create a mark class, and insert marks at the beginning and at the end of the environment with different values (the value actually doesn't matter, as far as I get, but it makes it easier to understand). Now, if the environment fits in one page the first and last values of the mark at a given shipout must differ, if they don't, it means the mark at the end went to the next page, and we issue the error.
No cross-reference or .aux file involved, works on the first run too.  ;-)

@cfr Regarding "fragility". This MWE may need some polishing, but technically, the use of marks for this kind of thing should be pretty robust, I think.

thanks for editing. re. fragility: I didn't mean the marks. I meant that's why I preferred the fitting approach to the label/ref one. the issue is the same for marks, but it doesn't apply to your proposal because you are only comparing them inside the output routine ;). like I said, this is a neat answer. (though it is an answer to a different question than the one I answered!)

@cfr Yes, yes, as I said this is a complement to your answer regarding the use case that was added later.

This looks interesting. Will investigate.
